# How to set Content-Length in response header for Jfree chart?

Tags: httpresponse, jfreechart

I have a servlet which is creating the jfree chart. By default it is returning tranfer-encoding as chunked. But I have to set the Content-Length in the response  header.

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartController.createChart();

          final int chartWidth = ChartUtils.calculateWidth(request);
          final int chartHeight = ChartHelper.getQuickViewChartHeight();

          final ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
          response.setContentType("image/png");       
          ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, chartWidth, chartHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304126/230513), it's not meaningful to set the content-length header *and* also use chunked transfer encoding. In either case, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5357882/230513), you can use [`ChartUtilities.encode()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc_old/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html#encodeAsPNG-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-) to determine the byte length of the encoded image array:

```
byte[] b = ChartUtilities.encode(chart.createBufferedImage(chartWidth, chartHeight));
int imageLength = b.length;
```

Later, you can `write()` the encoded image to the output stream:

```
out.write(b);
```